# Type error when trying to create a doc2vec model in gensim

Tags: python, gensim, doc2vec

I am trying to train a Doc2Vec model using gensim.

The dataset i am using is the 20 newsgroups dataset [1] which is included in sklearn's datasets module.

I have used the example in the gensim documentation to create the model.

```py
docs = newsgroups_train['data']
enumerated_docs = enumerate(docs)
documnets= [TaggedDocument(doc.split(),i) for i, doc in enumerated_docs]
model = Doc2Vec(documnets, vector_size=20, window=2, min_count=30, workers=4)
```

I checked every line of code, all seems to be working up to the line which initializes the model.

I  get a type error:
`TypeError: 'int' object is not iterable`

[1] https://scikit-learn.org/0.19/datasets/twenty_newsgroups.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Enumerate` returns an integer counter and the value in the list. So, in your third line of code, `i` is an integer. However, the second parameter of `TaggedDocument` function should be an iterable.

Comment: Even more specifically, the 2nd `tags` argument to `TaggedDocument` should be a true list – as later code will need to get its length, and access it by index, not just by in-order iteration. (In the common case where every doc has one unique ID, it will be a list with only one item.)